# S3 disposable url

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I need to create a S3 presigned url that expires after one use.

I have tried to create presigned url with near expiration date, but in my case is not enough.

is there a method to do this?

Comment: S3 offers no such functionality.  You will need to use some other service, such as Lambda, to serve up the content and track the lifecycle of the request with some database yourself.

Comment: You can use s3 object lambda. On each GET, the lambda checks the tag attached to the object. If no tag is present, add a tag and send back the object. If a tag is present, send back null. This way you don't need an extra db or an app to achieve this. Everything is serverless.